# How can I improve these comparisons?

Tags: vb.net, comparison, if-statement

I have 5 values, and I'm comparing them and trying to do some action depending on which value is the greatest.

The values are v1, v2, v3, v4 and v5

```
If (v1 > v2 And v1 > v3 And v1 > v4 And v1 > v5) Then
        l1st.Text = "Al-Haj Shaji Gul"
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.shajismal

ElseIf (v2 > v3 And v2 > v4 And v2 > v1 And v2 > v5) Then
        l1st.Text = "Nor huq"
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.norlhuq

ElseIf (v3 > v1 And v3 > v2 And v2 > v4 And v3 > v5) Then
        l1st.Text = "Darya Khan"
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.daryakhanpic

ElseIf (v4 > v1 And v4 > v2 And v4 > v3 And v4 > v5) Then
        l1st.Text = "Imran Khan"
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.Imran_Khan

ElseIf (v5 > v1 And v5 > v2 And v5 > v3 And v5 > v4) Then
        l1st.Text = "Zarnoor Afridi"
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.zarnorsmal
End If
```

Comment: In what way are you trying to make the code better?

Comment: it is complex and when the values become equal it dose not work

Comment: That is indeed a problem. Are there specific actions that you want to take if two or more of the variables share the greatest value? If not, the best thing you could do would be to change all the `>` to `>=`

Comment: It looks like you are just trying to sort the values, so put them in a list and sort them.

Comment: thanks jonhopkins , actualy these 5 values are the % of student and i want to show the name of the student who have highist %.

Comment: @LarsTech Maybe you're seeing something I'm not, but how does it look like he's trying to sort them? I honestly only see that it's finding which one is the biggest and do something depending on which one is the biggest

Comment: @jonhopkins Isn't that the same thing as sorting them?  Put them in a list, sort them, set the controls to the first item in the list.

Comment: @LarsTech How do you know that the first item, after being sorted, is `v1`? You need another piece of info.

Comment: @sangeen, you mentioned that there are cases where two or more of the values can be the same. What should be done if two are the same? Let's say v1 and v3 are the same. Should only v1 be shown? Or v3? Or both?

Comment: @LarsTech that would get really complicated really quickly. He's setting different controls to different values for each one. I'm not saying it can't be done. I've done it myself on a few occasions, but it's not optimal in my opinion.

Comment: only the gretest should be shown and if all 5 values are same/equal then should show equal msg.

Comment: @jonhopkins I only see one text control and one picturebox.  Different labels but they are all red.  I'm guessing a class should get involved that has these V values that associates each student with their value.

Comment: Ok. So what you need is to add another `ElseIf` that checks `(v1 = v2 And v2 = v3 And v3 = v4 And v4 = v5)` and show the equal message in that block

Comment: but if the values are 2,3,4,5,5 then should show the 5 and 5

Comment: So, v1 is Al-Haj Shaji Gul's percentage (grade, score, ?), v2 is Nor Huq's percentage, v3 is Darya Kahn's, and so on?  If so, why not have a list of students (if that is what this exercise represents), order it by percentage, and take the first one?  You will need a way to get the picture corresponding to the student as you probably don't want to store specific student images as resources.

Comment: i means if v1=2, v2=3, v3=4, v4=5 and v5=5 then show the msge that v4 and v5 are equal

Comment: @sangeen I just noticed you changed your accepted answer. I'm not so sure about VB.Net, but most other languages don't like it when multiple cases in a select have the same value. Does the answer you selected work the way you expect it to when two or more people share the highest sccore? I just want to be sure that the answer you accept is one that actually works, both for you and for other people who look at this question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an example:

```
Dim v_array(4) As Integer
Dim max_v As Integer
For i = 0 To 4
    v_array(i) = i + (Math.Rnd(15) * 10)
Next i

For Each v In v_array
    If v > max_v Then
        max_v = v
    End If
Next v

Select Case max_v
    Case v_array(0)
        MsgBox "Something"
    Case v_array(1)
        MsgBox "Something 1"
    Case v_array(2)
        MsgBox "Something 2"
    Case v_array(3)
        MsgBox "Something 3"
    Case v_array(4)
        MsgBox "Something 4"
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps at all. It gets the highest score and stores it in `max`. Then it checks all five of the values and for each one that is the same as `max`, ie is the highest, it sets the controls to the values for that student. If there are more than one with the highest score, it adds those students to the end of the textbox's text, like "Student1 = Student3". The only thing I couldn't get around is that the image will be the last student with the highest score.

```
Dim max As Integer = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}.Max
Dim multiple As Boolean = False

l1st.Text = ""
If (v1 = max) Then
        l1st.Text = "Al-Haj Shaji Gul"
        Label5.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.shajismal
        multiple = True
EndIf
If (v2 = max) Then
        If multiple = True Then
            l1st.Text = l1st.Text + " = "
        EndIf
        multiple = True
        l1st.Text = l1st.Text + "Nor huq"
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.norlhuq
EndIf
If (v3 = max) Then
        If multiple = True Then
            l1st.Text = l1st.Text + " = "
        EndIf
        multiple = True
        l1st.Text = l1st.Text + "Darya Khan"
        Label7.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.daryakhanpic
EndIf
If (v4 = max) Then
        If multiple = True Then
            l1st.Text = l1st.Text + " = "
        EndIf
        multiple = True
        l1st.Text = l1st.Text + "Imran Khan"
        Label8.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.Imran_Khan
EndIf
If (v5 = max) Then
        If multiple = True Then
            l1st.Text = l1st.Text + " = "
        EndIf
        multiple = True
        l1st.Text = l1st.Text + "Zarnoor Afridi"
        Label10.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Me.PictureBox12.Image = Global.shaji.My.Resources.Resources.zarnorsmal
End If
```

Comment: yeah jonhopkins it works, but jonhopkins there is one big problem occured by you, you really impress me and i want to be your friend but  how i will find you in facebook????

Comment: @ThinkingStiff, thank you for that improvement. Didn't think of doing that. sangeen, the change to the first line might be useful to take note of for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Put the variables in an array first; this makes searching the maximum easier

```
Dim v = New () {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}
Dim i As Integer = Array.IndexOf(v, v.Max()) + 1
Select Case i
    Case 1
        ' Process when v1 is maximum
    Case 2
        ' Process when v2 is maximum
    Case 3
        ' Process when v3 is maximum
    Case 4
        ' Process when v4 is maximum
    Case 5
        ' Process when v5 is maximum
End Select
```

Of cause you could also define just one variable `v` as array to start with, instead of using individual variables.

```
Dim v = New Integer(4) {}
v(0) = 10
v(1) = 15
...
```